# Async/Await Mongoose doesn't always run correctly

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I'm using mongoose with an async/await function to query the DB. A few calls to the api doesn't return the necessary data. Below is the controller code

```
exports.GetAllUrls = async function(req, res, next){
try {
    var urlsArray = []; 
    await Url.find({uid: req.params.uid}, function (err, urls) {
        urls.forEach(function(url){
            urlsArray.push(url);
            console.log(url);
        });
    });
    console.log("Await called");
    return res.status(200).json({reply: urlsArray});
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

}

There are a few times where the "Await called" is logged before the url data is logged.

Node Request Log:

```
Await called
GET /api/screens/GetAllUrls/0WyaS0ePeaS54zz9cAgCUnxoE1i1 200 31.348 ms - 12
{ _id: 5b0ad7effa8e80800153fa04,
  url: 'https://yahoo.com',
  timestamp: 2018-05-27T16:31:10.638Z,
  uid: '0WyaS0ePeaS54zz9cAgCUnxoE1i1',
  __v: 0 }
```

As seen in the logs, the function seems to proceed before the await function is called, but my understanding is that execution is paused until the await is completed and returned. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `await` only waits for an async operation if you're awaiting a promise that is linked to the async operation.  It seems likely that `Url.find()` when you pass it a callback does NOT return a promise, thus `await` has nothing to do. You need to use a promisified version of that function to use it with `await` or make your own with `util.promisify()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the specifics on that library or method, but I can tell you why it's not working.

"await" will pause only when the right hand side of the statement returns a "Promise" object. In your code example, it seems that the function takes a callback. Callbacks, though asynchronous, are not promises. Perhaps you can check that library's API docs to see if it can return a Promise instead of taking the callback?

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing **callbacks** with **async-await**. Don't do that. Please study how they work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Your route handler should be:

```
exports.GetAllUrls = async function(req, res, next){
  try {
      const urlsArray = await Url.find({uid: req.params.uid}).exec()
      return res.status(200).json({reply: urlsArray});
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
}
```

1. `.find()` returns a `Query` object: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find
2. `.exec()` returns a `Promise`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec